# How to simulate SPA navigation in my index.html file with raw javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, single-page-application

Basically I need to set up my index.html file to handle all URL routes (but I think this part is done on the web server end) and be able to update the URL route (with back & forward button functionality) via Javascript without page refreshes/transitions.

What is the easiest way to make this work in raw js without any frameworks?

Or is it so complicated that I'd be better off going with a lightweight angular app to wrap this in?

Comment: _"Basically I need to set up my index.html file to handle all URL routes (but I think this part is done on the web server end)"_ that's part of the server configuration. _"and be able to update the URL route (with back & forward button functionality) via Javascript without page refreshes/transitions."_ That's done with the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: @jabaa Routing can be implemented in the browser in vanilla JavaScript, using the History API. There are many tutorials about it on the web.

Comment: This is great, thanks! History API is exactly what I needed... Guess I simply didn't know the term to search for.

Comment: @kol Yes, routing can be implemented in the browser but people usually expect that it also works with page reloads and bookmarks. You have to configure the backend to redirect all requests to the index page and let it handle the route. Of course you could go the AngularJs way and use fragments or query parameters as a workaround. The common way to configure such a server is to check if a file exists for the requested path and respond with index.html if the file doesn't exist, e.g. with express-history-api-fallback for Express